# VB.net 2017 - size of 2 or more datagriviews in a form

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to have 2 or more DGV "conected" in a form and resize them according to the number of rows?

Example: When I add row to top DGV, it grows and should move the bottom DGV down.

Tried it with panels it does not work. Panel creates scroll bars. When I use just DGV's they just overlap. I need this for Printform.

Thanks.

Comment: With a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-overview) or a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview), maybe?

Comment: Yeah, TableLayoutPanel does the trick. Thanks a lot!!